# Retain trailer back to the flat file in SSIS

Tags: ssis, etl

I would like to retain the `trailer/footer` of my flat file after doing a derived `column transformation`.

```
20101231|A2456395F|01066885|8.00|0.00|9101|XDS
20101231|G1352486C|01066931|24.00|3.00|9020|EFC  
End of Record: 000106662 Date of Extraction: 20110427 10:38:55
```

For example I have a flat file as shown above, after the derived column transformation (to convert the date format). The flow will be to a Flat File destination. The result now is as shown below without the (`End of Record.......`)

```
31.12.2010|S2648995D|01066885|8.00|0.00|9101|SPR
31.12.2010|S1812486F|01066931|24.00|3.00|9020|SPR
```

I need help with retaining that "`End of record.......`" in my flat file destination.

Thank you!

Comment: You can append to an existing file a few different ways. You can run a DOS COPY command from an existing file. You can run a script task to open the file. Script might be easiest. Are you familiar with C#?

Comment: I would use a script task.

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid script task? as in Script Component in SSIS? So how can i do it? Can you kindly help? Thanks =)

Comment: I typed "SSIS script task add footer" into google and found this: http://microsoft-ssis.blogspot.com.au/2015/02/add-footer-to-flat-file.html Why don't you try this and get back with any specific questions.